# Does datatables cache results for an ajaxSource?

Tags: datatables

I have embedded jquery datatables inside a portlet war file and am experiencing some funny behaviour which I need some explanation for.

This is what my javascript looks like...http://pastebin.com/qXpwt9A7

Here is the scenario.

1. I open the webpage and do a keyword search on 'TextA'
   Result: A ajax request is sent to the server to load the jquery datatable.
2. Without closing the browser I do a keyword search on 'TextB'. 
   Result: A ajax request is sent to the server to load the jquery datatable.
3. Without closing the browser I do a keyword search on 'TextA' again.
   Result: A request is not sent to the server. But my datatable is smart enough to remember the results retrieved in step 1 amnd it displays the results on the page.

This actually works well for me but I don't know why it is happening.

If I had to guess I'm thinking there must be some smarts in datatables where it caches the results for an ajax source where the arguments are the same so that it doesn't have to fire off the request for that ajax source again.

Am I right?
I am using data tables 1.9.4.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By default, DataTables v.1.9.4 prevents request caching in `fnServerData` function, notice `"cache": false` in excerpt from the DataTables source code below.

```
  "fnServerData": function ( sUrl, aoData, fnCallback, oSettings ) {
     oSettings.jqXHR = $.ajax( {
        "url":  sUrl,
        "data": aoData,
        "success": function (json) {
           if ( json.sError ) {
              oSettings.oApi._fnLog( oSettings, 0, json.sError );
           }

           $(oSettings.oInstance).trigger('xhr', [oSettings, json]);
           fnCallback( json );
        },
        "dataType": "json",
        "cache": false,
        "type": oSettings.sServerMethod,
        "error": function (xhr, error, thrown) {
           if ( error == "parsererror" ) {
              oSettings.oApi._fnLog( oSettings, 0, "DataTables warning: JSON data from "+
                 "server could not be parsed. This is caused by a JSON formatting error." );
           }
        }
     } );
  }
```

However in your code you're overriding `fnServerData` and using `$.getJSON()` which is a shorthand function for [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) without specifying `cache` option. Default value for `cache` options is `true`, that is why your requests are being cached.

Below is an excerpt from jQuery manual:

> `cache` (default: `true`, `false` for `dataType` `'script'` and `'jsonp'`)
>
> Type: Boolean
>
> If set to `false`, it will force requested pages not to be
>   cached by the browser. Note: Setting `cache` to `false` will only work
>   correctly with HEAD and GET requests. It works by appending
>   "_={timestamp}" to the GET parameters. The parameter is not needed for
>   other types of requests, except in IE8 when a POST is made to a URL
>   that has already been requested by a GET.

Comment: thank you so much. This is a brilliant answer. As I mentioned already I am actually happy with the caching of a request with the same parameters however I just needed an explanation for why it was  happening.