# How to prevent the datatable pulling data when the user paginate backward?

Tags: jquery, datatables

Im using datatable with serverside processing.

Sample scenario is that:

When the user paginate into the datatable *page 1*, *page 2* and then *page 3* it will pull the data from the serverside. Is there a way that when the user paginate back, since the data has been pulled into the server, it will not pull anymore. I want the previous data stored. Is there any way to do it? Currently I'm reading the [stateSave](https://datatables.net/reference/option/stateSave) property of datatable. TIA

Answer (score 0):

As you said you should take a look at the [stateSave](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/state_save.html) that does what you are looking for:

> DataTables has the option of being able to save the state of a table
>   (its paging position, ordering state etc) so that is can be restored
>   when the user reloads a page, or comes back to the page after visiting
>   a sub-page.

But as you are doing server-side processing, you can also look at [Pipelining](https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/pipeline.html), to reduce Ajax calls for pagination, like in this example:

```
//
// Pipelining function for DataTables. To be used to the `ajax` option of DataTables
//
$.fn.dataTable.pipeline = function ( opts ) {
    // Configuration options
    var conf = $.extend( {
        pages: 5,     // number of pages to cache
        url: '',      // script url
        data: null,   // function or object with parameters to send to the server
                      // matching how `ajax.data` works in DataTables
        method: 'GET' // Ajax HTTP method
    }, opts );

    // Private variables for storing the cache
    var cacheLower = -1;
    var cacheUpper = null;
    var cacheLastRequest = null;
    var cacheLastJson = null;

    return function ( request, drawCallback, settings ) {
        var ajax          = false;
        var requestStart  = request.start;
        var drawStart     = request.start;
        var requestLength = request.length;
        var requestEnd    = requestStart + requestLength;

        if ( settings.clearCache ) {
            // API requested that the cache be cleared
            ajax = true;
            settings.clearCache = false;
        }
        else if ( cacheLower < 0 || requestStart < cacheLower || requestEnd > cacheUpper ) {
            // outside cached data - need to make a request
            ajax = true;
        }
        else if ( JSON.stringify( request.order )   !== JSON.stringify( cacheLastRequest.order ) ||
                  JSON.stringify( request.columns ) !== JSON.stringify( cacheLastRequest.columns ) ||
                  JSON.stringify( request.search )  !== JSON.stringify( cacheLastRequest.search )
        ) {
            // properties changed (ordering, columns, searching)
            ajax = true;
        }

        // Store the request for checking next time around
        cacheLastRequest = $.extend( true, {}, request );

        if ( ajax ) {
            // Need data from the server
            if ( requestStart < cacheLower ) {
                requestStart = requestStart - (requestLength*(conf.pages-1));

                if ( requestStart < 0 ) {
                    requestStart = 0;
                }
            }

            cacheLower = requestStart;
            cacheUpper = requestStart + (requestLength * conf.pages);

            request.start = requestStart;
            request.length = requestLength*conf.pages;

            // Provide the same `data` options as DataTables.
            if ( typeof conf.data === 'function' ) {
                // As a function it is executed with the data object as an arg
                // for manipulation. If an object is returned, it is used as the
                // data object to submit
                var d = conf.data( request );
                if ( d ) {
                    $.extend( request, d );
                }
            }
            else if ( $.isPlainObject( conf.data ) ) {
                // As an object, the data given extends the default
                $.extend( request, conf.data );
            }

            settings.jqXHR = $.ajax( {
                "type":     conf.method,
                "url":      conf.url,
                "data":     request,
                "dataType": "json",
                "cache":    false,
                "success":  function ( json ) {
                    cacheLastJson = $.extend(true, {}, json);

                    if ( cacheLower != drawStart ) {
                        json.data.splice( 0, drawStart-cacheLower );
                    }
                    if ( requestLength >= -1 ) {
                        json.data.splice( requestLength, json.data.length );
                    }

                    drawCallback( json );
                }
            } );
        }
        else {
            json = $.extend( true, {}, cacheLastJson );
            json.draw = request.draw; // Update the echo for each response
            json.data.splice( 0, requestStart-cacheLower );
            json.data.splice( requestLength, json.data.length );

            drawCallback(json);
        }
    }
};

// Register an API method that will empty the pipelined data, forcing an Ajax
// fetch on the next draw (i.e. `table.clearPipeline().draw()`)
$.fn.dataTable.Api.register( 'clearPipeline()', function () {
    return this.iterator( 'table', function ( settings ) {
        settings.clearCache = true;
    } );
} );


//
// DataTables initialisation
//
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": $.fn.dataTable.pipeline( {
            url: 'scripts/server_processing.php',
            pages: 5 // number of pages to cache
        } )
    } );
} );
```

Doing both of them, you could cache & reduce the server requests, improving performance & server time.

Depending on how you request your data to the server, you should be aware that by default, `DataTables` prevents request caching in `fnServerData` function, but you could override `fnServerData` and use `$.getJSON()` which is a shorthand function for `$.ajax()` without specifying cache option. Default value for cache options is true, and your requests will be cached.

Extracted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30068319/does-datatables-cache-results-for-an-ajaxsource).

Last tip will be to take a look to 'Deferred loading of data' also, as you could read in their [docs](https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/defer_loading.html):

> When using DataTables with server-side processing, the default
>   behaviour is to have DataTables automatically make an Ajax call and
>   load the data, removing anything which might have already been in the
>   table. However, this behaviour might not always be desirable when the
>   first page of the table has already been preloaded in the HTML (which
>   you might do to ensure accessibility or for performance reasons).
>
> This automatic Ajax call to get the first page of data can be
>   overridden by using the deferLoading initialisation property

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion bro. But I'm not using server side anymore. I came up with single query to select all rows besides I have only 4k-5k row of data.